# I have 12V to 1500 Watts Inverter

Tags: voltage

I have 12v to 1500 watts Inverter, if i use my Electricity power  (220V to 12V ) ( not use Battery for 12V )and connect with Inverter , will my electricity bill decrease ? 
what happened if I use ?

Step 
 1)Direct Electricity convert to 12v,
 2)Then 12V to Inverter 1500W ,
 3)Then Home appliance ( Tube Light, Fan Etc ),

Help me to Save Electricity and bill minimize .

Answer (score 6):

I cannot help you to minimize your electricity bill but I will show you why your idea won't work.

If I understood correctly, your system will be like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOZcUs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose 220Vac/12VDC converter has an efficiency of %95 (heavily optimistic expectation) and 12VDC/220Vac inverter has an efficiency of %90 (ultra-heavily optimistic expectation). Since they are cascade-connected, total system efficiency will be the multiplication of those two:

\$e = e1 \cdot e2 = 0.95 \cdot 0.90 = 0.855\$

What does this number mean? If your home appliances use, say, 1000W then total power drawn from power grid will be 1000/0.855 = 1170W.

See? A terrible idea!

I'm not an expert about energy efficiency but at least I can say:

- Use LED lamps instead of fluorescent or incandescent lamps.
- Avoid over-usage.
- We Turks have a motto: "Lüzumsuz ise söndür" which means "Turn it off if not using".
- We have an infinite source: Sun light. Make use of it.
- Finally, google "minimize electricity cost".